# Why is it that the list variables in this code gets values in them backwards? HP is the last assigned variable despite being there first in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a simple program (I am a beginner at python) where I fight a monster with random assigned values. I used 2 lists with 4 variables each depicting hp atk def and spd. They get assigned a random number of 10 to 15 and get multiplied by 2. I don't really know what I am doing wrong here.

```
import random

monsters = ["slime","goblin","troll","dryad","bard","clown"]

hp,atk,dfn,spd = 0,0,0,0
mhp,matk,mdfn,mspd = 0,0,0,0

stats = [hp,atk,dfn,spd]
mstats = [hp,atk,dfn,spd]
damage = 0
defend = 0
action = "none"

name = input()

print("Your name is " + name + ", time to battle!")

for x in stats:

    stats[x] = random.randint(10,15) * 2

    print("Your stats(hp/a/d/s): " + str(stats[x]))

for y in mstats:

    mstats[y] = random.randint(10,15) * 2

    print("Monster stats(hp/a/d/s): " + str(mstats[y]))

while stats[hp] > 0 or mstats[hp] > 0:
    print("What will you do? 1 for attack, 2 for defend, others to give up")
    action = input()
    if action == "1":
        damage = stats[atk] / 2 + random.randint(1,5)
        mstats[hp] = mstats[hp] - damage
        print("You slash the monster for " + str(damage) + " damage!" )
        print("Monster HP: " + str(mstats[hp]))
        damage = mstats[atk] / 2
        stats[hp] = stats[hp] - damage
        print("The monster slashes you for " + str(damage) + " damage!")
        print("Your HP: " + str(stats[hp]))
    if action == "2":
        damage = mstats[atk] / 2 - random.randint(3,5)
        if damage > 0:
            stats[hp] = stats[hp] - damage
            print("The monster slashes you for " + str(damage) + " damage!")
        print("Your HP: " + str(stats[hp]))
    if action != "1" and action != "2":
        stats[hp] = 0
    if stats[hp] < 0 or stats[hp] == 0:
        print("You lose!")
    if mstats[hp] < 0:
        print("You win!")
```

Hopefully this code isn't a mess, I thank you all in advance if extra corrections can be given.

Comment: `for x in stats:` iterates over four zeroes, setting the first element in the array four times. After that I'd expect the first element to be some random number and the other three to still be zero. If you're going to store these things in a list, shouldn't you be setting their indexes to *different* values? Better yet, *use a dictionary* and name them.

Comment: @userS that tag wasn't needed at all, the issue is nothing to do with random behaviour.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How can I do that? A little help would be nice.

Comment: Well, do you see where you're setting them all to the same value, zero? Try setting them to the actual indices you want the values to be at, instead. But your question doesn't currently make sense because I wouldn't expect them to get set "backwards", I'd expect only the first to get set; cut this down to a [mcve].

Comment: @jonrsharpe I do see them. I guess I should try "for x in range(3):". Hope it works.

Comment: I would only expect that to set the first *3*, but it's a step in the right direction!

Comment: @jonrsharpe It worked now. Thank you. And yes I set it to 4 instead of 3.